# what condition can I use for this process

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

```bash
if [ "$Retrieve_api_key" -x "$Create_retrieve_api_key" ]
then 
  echo " $Retrieve_api_key "
else
  echo " $Create_retrieve_api_key "
fi
```

so the values of the variable Retrieve_api_key= let say "curl -u abc"
Create_retrieve_api_key=let say "curl -u 123"

What I'm trying to do is basically if "$Retrieve_api_key" value get printed then skip the next "$Create_retrieve_api_key" but if $Retrieve_api_key value  doesn't get printed then execute "$Create_retrieve_api_key"

How do I go about this please? This is a Bash script.

Comment: What do you mean by "get executed"? How could a value be executed?

Comment: string I meant to say

Comment: so if the string of the first value doest get executed that should skip and execute the next

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: This is still not clear, because strings don't get executed. They can be read, assigned, printed, passed around, but what do you mean by "executed"?

Comment: pls check again

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
api_key=$(curl -u abc)
if [ -z "$api_key" ]
then
     api_key=$(curl -u 123)
fi
echo $api_key
```

Firstly, try to retrieve api key, if it is empty, then create it. Finally use it.

Comment: can you rephrase this by using api_key1
api_key2